# On Net interest

Tags: macroeconomics

On my book it says that net interest is "The interest domestic businesses pay minus the interest
they receive, plus interest earned from foreigners."

But how can businesses receive interest?

Comment: Why shouldn't they receive interest? What do you think is preventing it?

Comment: I thought only households receive interest because they deposit their savings in financial institutions.  Thats why im confused. I mean, for example, does Pepsi receive interest or is it only banks?

Comment: Where do you think businesses deposit their cash?

Answer (score 1):

Banks and other financial institutions are businesses.

Comment: My book doesn't even mention that, thanks.